# jruby jndi connection rake aborted when run assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jndi

I follow istructions here https://gist.github.com/1564440 to configure a jndi connection for my jruby on rails application.
When I run rake assets:precompile I have this error:

rake aborted!
jdbc adapter requires driver class and url

What I've missed?

Comment: Sounds like your `database.yml` is not correct. Please check it, or add it here.

Comment: development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: example_development
  pool: 5
  username: xxx
  password: xxx

  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: example_test
  pool: 5
  username: xxx
  password: xxx

  host: localhost
  port: 5432

production:
  adapter: jdbc
  jndi: java:comp/env/jdbc/albofornitori
  driver: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  wait_timeout: 5
  pool: 5